# Referencing a synchronized method inside another synchronized method

Tags: java, multithreading

I have two methods.

Both of them are method synchronized.If i call one method from another ,will that be a deadlock situation?

Comment: Are the two methods part of the same class?

Comment: That depends on the lock object. Can you give more details on what you mean, i.e. instance methods, static methods, methods with an internal synchronized block?

Answer (score 4):

No, assuming that both methods are in the same class (and are both `static` or both not `static`). A `synchronized` method is only entered when the thread trying to enter can get a hold of the monitor object (e.g. `this`). As the thread already has acquired the monitor, it can simply enter the second method without any further trouble.

Comment: That's called a reentrant lock.

Answer (score 0):

If `thread 1` acquires a lock on `A` and also wants to lock `B`.
`Thread 2` has a lock on `B` and wants a lock on `A` too.
This is a deadlock.
Else, everything is possible.

Answer (score 0):

It depends:

- if these are synchronized methods on two (or more) different objects,
- if multiple threads access these objects,
- and if the lock order on these objects can vary (in one case object1->object2 and other case object2->object1)

then yes, you can get deadlock.

However if you are talking about synchronized methods on one and the same object, then it is not possible to get deadlock: the monitor of an object is re-entrant: if you already hold it, you can request the monitor again (enter a synchronized block on the same object).